# Unable to capture insert/update/delete in log Analytics (using synapse dedicated SQL POOL audit data)

Tags: azure-synapse

Unable to capture insert/update/delete operations in log Analytics. Using synapse dedicated sql pool audit data).

Is it possible to audit the insert/update/delete in log Analytics?

Could you please provide answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

If the ask is , does log analytics capture the insert/update/delete records , then the answer is NO it does not . I think you can be a bit more elaborate on the ask .

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.any document for that I mean why it is not capturing the insert/update/delete records?

Comment: Why it is not capturing the operations like Delete/insert/update any specific reasons? Please let me know briefly